# I have to show a pop on click of a span but elements not appearing in the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a div pop up on click of a span. Even though the code inside the function is executing, the div is not at all visible in the DOM. 
Am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
<span id="test" onClick={()=>this.bindPopUpData("test")}>
```

Here I am calling the function to bind popup.

```
bindPopUpData=(dimension) =>{ 

return (

  <div id="">
      <div className="details_table">
          <div className="close_popup">
              <span className="icon-Close"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

   ); 
}
```

-- Here I am trying to bind that popup

Can someone please tell where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your event handler is just returning a value, you're not telling the browser to put it anywhere.

Option 1: build the popup into the DOM with `display:none` and use your event handler to show/hide it.

Option 2: make your event handler inject the popup into the DOM with `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild` functionalities.

With React I'd recommend option 1 because you can make the popup a component and only render it *if* the parent component detects the event.

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showpopup: false
    }
    this.myHandler = this.myHandler.bind(this)
  }
  myHandler () {
    this.setState({showpopup: !showpopup})
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <section>
       <span onClick={this.myHandler}></span>
        {this.state.showpopup ? <Popup /> : ''}
      </section>
    )}
}
```